# Refresh <div id="RefhreshableDiv"> content on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Let me get straight to the point.
Somewhere in my website i have the following code:

```
<?php  
echo '<div id="RefreshableDiv">';
/* performs changes to database,
   depending on whether button1 was clicked or not 
   with the help of: if (isset($_POST['button1'])) */

/* retrieves information from database */   

/* creates a button with id="button1", with background image 
   depending on retrieved database information */

echo '</div>';
?>
```

I am trying to give my site the following functionality:

- User clicks `button1`
- only the part of the page inside `<div>` with `id "RefreshableDiv"` gets refreshed 
  (and as a result button1 background image changes.)

Is what I am trying to do even possible ? I am expecting the usage of ajax, i think.

Comment: yes you have to use ajax i poste an anwser o a simlar question let me get the link

Comment: `$('#button1').click(function() { $.ajax({ ... }).done(function(data) { $('#RefreshableDiv').html(data); }) });`

Comment: @Regent as i have never tried ajax code in my life, let me ask what am i supposed to write in `...` in `$.ajax({ ... }` , and what other changes i need to make to make your code work ?

Comment: 1. The whole code should be wrapped with `$(document).ready(function() { your code });`. 2. About `$.ajax` you can read in [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), but you at least should specify url for request (for example, `$.ajax({ url: url_to_server })` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok first have a page where there is the database changes and stuff you need and name it 
something like : `pagerefrech.php`
lest say its code is the folowing :

```
<?php 
//selecting fr database and doing what do you want to do
//this page will return whats gonna be inside the div
//to get the parameter sent by $.post you use $_POST['nameofparam']
//exemple : 
  echo "THIS IS THE CONTENT OF THE DIV";
?>
```

and your button cilck event is  :

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.post(//or $.get if you want to use GET request
    "pagerefrech.php",//path to teh page
    {
    param1  : value1 ,
    param2 : value2//for sending some post vars if you dont want to set it to null
    },
    function(data){//data contains the contenet returned by the page "pagerefrech.php"
    $('#RefreshableDiv').html(data);
    //change here the background image of the button
    $('#button1').css({"background-image" : "yourvaluegoeshere"});
    });//end of $.post function
});//end of button1.click
```

**Explaining :**
$.post send a POST request to the page `pagerefrech.php` nad get the result
param1 and param2 and param3..... are paramers you can add them to send them to the page if not you can let it as {} without anything inside , this will be exactly like you are sending POST variables like input or select values.

**SIMPLE EXEMPLE :**
create a page named `test.php` with this code :

```
<?php echo "cotent recieved"; ?>
```

create an html page with this code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="test" id="but1" />
<div id="refrech"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#but1').click(function(){
        $.post(
        "test.php",
        {
        },
        function(data){
        $('#refrech').html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PS :** dont forget to add the jquery library to the page in your test hope it was clear

Comment: where is the code `$post(...)` going to go ? what are the `param1` , `param2` values going to be ? and what is the `data` going to look like ?

Comment: i am sorry , i am total noob in ajax, please give me a solid example if you can , it doesn't have to be detailed , but i need to understand what is what , as i am a complete beginner :S

Comment: thank you very much friend , i will try this code as soon as i can

Comment: um , `pagerefrech.php` contains the content of the div,  so why do we need this `$('#button1').css({"background-image" : "yourvaluegoeshere"});` ? since this information will already be in `pagerefrech.php`, no ?

Comment: i am going to exams right now , i will see your code in detail very soon when i return, i am sure i will figure it out :)

Comment: yes you can put it int the page but like this
`<script>
$('#button1').css({"background-image" : "yourvaluegoeshere"});
</script>`
btw thats to change the background image of the button ;)